# Weird array structure in preg_match_all output PHP

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match-all

I have pregmatch_all function that **scrapes** emails ! But the output is kind of weirdly structured and I don't manage to restructure it.

```
$str = "Service Client ouvert : du lundi au vendredi de 9h à 20h le samedi de 9h à 18h 01 75 85 83 83 hello@soshape.com So Shape France / Site créé par KL Consult"
$pattern = '/[a-z0-9_\-\+\.]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,4})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i';
$preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $output);
print_r($output);
```

returns

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => hello@soshape.com ) [1] => Array ( [0] => com ) )
```

**Two things please:**

- How can I get rid of the "com" array ?
- How can I restructure the array in order to get : Array ( [0] => hello@soshape.com )

Any idea ? (if my question is not clear, do not hesitate to let me know. I'll be glad to explain further !)

Comment: Add optional [parameter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) for another output. `preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $output, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Markus wrote in the comment lets look at the `PREG_PATTERN_ORDER` flag:

> Orders results so that $matches[0] is an array of full pattern
> matches, $matches[1] is an array of strings matched by the first
> parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

From the documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

Because your patten include `()` as in `([a-z]{2,4})` the `.com` is catched as well.

If you only want the emails you can use the `PREG_PATTERN_ORDER` which will return the matches in index 0 of the return array (as you don't want the parenthesized subpattern you can ignore the following indexes)

So you can do:

```
$preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $output, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($output[0]);
```